# How can I get the start and end time of a calendar event in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

The `getStartTime()` and `getEndTime()` is only returning the date. How can I get the start and end time of the event?

```
var allEvents = calendar.getEvents(new Date('June 3, 2020'), new Date('August 6, 2020'));

var startDateTime = allEvents[j].getStartTime();

var endDateTime = allEvents[j].getEndTime();
```

Answer (score 1):

`startDateTime` and `endDateTime` are **Date** objects, meaning you can apply all the [relevant methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

```
var allEvents = calendar.getEvents(new Date('June 3, 2020'), new Date('August 6, 2020'));

var startDateTime = allEvents[j].getStartTime();
var startDateTime24 = startDateTime.getHours() + ":" + startDateTime.getMinutes()

var endDateTime = allEvents[j].getEndTime(); 
var endDateTime24 = endDateTime.getHours() + ":" + endDateTime.getMinutes()
```

Now `startDateTime24` and `endDateTime24` contain the time of the start and end of the event respectively in the 24-hour notation in the form **hh:mm**.

---

Note in the code I assume that `calendar` holds a reference to an instance of `CalendarApp`.

Comment: Marios, about your first remark - most likely, the OP already obtained a reference to an instance of `Calendar`, and the variable `calendar` holds it, on which the method is called: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#getEvents(Date,Date)

Comment: I am not saying you are wrong, just probably add a disclaimer - no need to complicate life for the OP :) On that note, afaik it is recommended to be used chained with `getDefaultCalendar()`